# Linux - crear usuario

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, debian-9, ubuntu-server

he creado un usuario con el comando

```
adduser jgil
```

Esto me ha creado una carpeta /home/jgil

Dicho usuario puede conectarse por sftp (ya que tenemos capado ftp por el puerto 21) y puede ver su carpeta /home/jgil, pero también puede ver la del resto de usuarios como por ejemplo /home/emartinez o bien /home/dfernandez

Existe alguna manera de "capar" esto?

Y otra pregunta relacionada con la mismo, quiero hacer un usuario con otro "login" por ejemplo "jgil2" que pueda acceder al /home/jgil pero solo en modo lectura , es decir que no pueda borrar nada de ese directorio.

Es eso posible?

Gracias.

Comment: planteas dos preguntas en una, mejor una cada vez :) Sobre lo de que solo vea su directorio, debes "enjaular" al usuario: https://blog.desdelinux.net/como-enjaular-jail-a-usuarios-que-se-conecten-por-ssh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la mejor solución es creando grupos de usuarios y asignandole permisos de acceso a dichos grupos. Linux nos permite hacer esto para poder administrar los permisos de los usuarios de una forma flexible.

Para crear un grupo de usuarios utilizamos el comando:

```
sudo groupadd <nombredelgrupo>
```

Para agregar un usuario a un grupo utilizamos el siguiente comando:

```
sudo usermod -g <nombredelgrupo> -a <usuario>
```

Este comando asignara el grupo  como grupo primario al que pertenece .

Después lo que debemos hacer es cambiar el grupo a las carpetas que creamos que deben ser accedidas solamente por sus miembros, con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo chgrp -R <group> <folder_path>
```

En este caso, crear un grupo en el que solamente estuviera "jgil" y asignando dicho grupo a carpeta de usuario "/home/jgil", de esta forma nadie más que el usuario jgil podría acceder a su carpeta. Si suponemos que creamos un nuevo grupo llamado "grupojgil" para realizar toda esta gestión de permisos, los comandos serían los siguientes:

```
sudo groupadd grupojgil
sudo usermod -g grupojgil -a jgil
sudo chgrp -R grupojgil "/home/jgil"
```

Para evitar que "jgil" accediera al resto de usuarios, deberíamos cambiar los permisos de ejecución sobre la carpeta de usuario del resto de usuarios con el comando:

```
sudo chmod -R 744 /home/emartinez
sudo chmod -R 744 /home/dfernandez
```

De esta forma la gente que pertenece a un mismo grupo puede acceder en modo lectura a la carpeta de usuario pero no podrá modificar ni ejecutar nada, y los usuarios que no pertenezcan al mismo grupo que estos usuario (en este caso emartinez y dfernandez) no podrán ni siquiera acceder en modo lectura.

Con respecto a poder dar permisos al usuario "jgil2" solamente de lectura a la carpeta de "jgil", debemos asignar el nuevo grupo de "jgil" a "jgil2":

```
sudo usermod -g grupojgil -a jgil2
```

Y debemos dar permiso solamente de lectura a los miembros del grupo sobre la carpeta del usuario jgil:

```
sudo chmod -R 744 /home/jgil
```

De esta forma los miembros del nuevo grupo de jgil solamente podrán acceder en modo lectura a su carpeta.

Saludos,
Raul